# How to expand a fixed width select box's dropdown to the left instead of right?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/9pyh2/

```
<style type="text/css">
   select {width:200px;}
</style>

<form>
   <select><option value="">Choose one</option>
      <option>First choice</option>
      <option>Second choice</option>
      <option>Really long third choice that makes the dropdown expand etc etc etc etc etc</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Is it possible to make the drop down menu expand to the left instead of the right when there's a really long option?

Comment: Here is a hack to do it using `rtl`: http://jsfiddle.net/9pyh2/1/

Comment: Thanks, looking for a way to do it so it looks like a normal drop down though.  Arrow right, text left.

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible solution

If you're willing to absolutely position your select menu you can use the following technique.

Here's a <kbd>**[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9pyh2/3/)**</kbd>.

#### Code

Wrap your element in a relatively positioned parent:

```
<form class="relative">
  <select class="ddm">
    <option value="1">Fly</option>
    <option value="2">Lizard</option>
    <option value="3">Snake</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And apply the following styles:

```
.relative { position: relative; }

.ddm {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This will allow the select menu to expand only to the left.